# -Guser.classpath=arhivo.jar not load .jar

Tags: java, jmeter, classpath

I am using JMeter 5.0 mode no GUI and OpenJDK Runtime Environment Corretto-8.322.06.1 (build 1.8.0_322-b06)

```
jmeter.bat -f -Ghilos=1 -Gsubida=1 -Gciclo=1 -GDatosCajero=DT_TramasATMPropios.csv -Guser.classpath=trama.jar -n -LERROR -t Cajeros_distribuidos.jmx -l result.csv -Djmeter.save.saveservice.output_format=csv -Ljmeter.engine=DEBUG
```

error parameter

```
-Guser.classpath=file.jar
```

take parameters globally in jmeter.log

> INFO o.a.j.JMeter: Setting Global property: user.classpath=trama.jar

[Jmeter.log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9EDe2.png)

error

> ERROR o.a.j.u.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method: eval  Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import Cajeros.RecepcionParametrosCajeros; import java.util.concurrent.ThreadLoc . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Class: RecepcionParametrosCajeros not found in namespace

property in the non-GUI JMeter command, but it does not take the .jar, when I use the property with

```
-Juser.classpath=file.jar
```

if it takes it, it also takes the rego global variables with -G

work globally with -G for distributed testing

Comment: Hi LMR and welcome. Do please try and add all the tags that are relevant. Also include the full command and a description of the context. If applicable, runtime environment (which Java & JMeter version) also can help. You can add stuff to the question by hitting [edit].

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your issue using the following dummy simple class:

```
package Cajeros;

public class RecepcionParametrosCajeros {

    public RecepcionParametrosCajeros() {

    }

    public String foo() {
        return "foo";
    }
}
```

importing the jar as:

```
jmeter -Juser.classpath=trama.jar
```

and invoking it like:

```
import Cajeros.RecepcionParametrosCajeros;

String foo = new RecepcionParametrosCajeros().foo();

log.info("Got string " + foo);
```

So double check that the file is present in JMeter's "bin" directory

More information:

- [JMeter's Classpath](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#classpath)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)

Also be aware of the following recommendations:

1. [Always use the latest version of JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#use_latest_version), consider migrating to [JMeter 5.5](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-5-5)
2. [Since JMeter 3.1 it's recommended to use JSR223 Test Elements and Groovy language](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#bsh_scripting) for scripting. It might also resolve your problem as Beanshell is not 100% Java compatible and you may face problems with generics, inner classes, features introduced after Java 5 and so on.